# Firebase rules - check for ios

Tags: android, ios, firebase

I'm using firebase for my iOS + android app.

I want to remove my iOS app and leave only the android app. (I know its a weird request).
In order to do that I want to block requests to firebase for my iOS app but not from my android app.

So my question is - 
How can I block the request for my iOS app on firebase without destroying my android app.

Can I use the firebase rules in some manner?

Can I remove my iOS app from firebase somehow?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can actually delete an app from your Firebase project, so request coming from deleted app wont be responded because the app does not exist and in the case of iOS, the .plist firebase file used for auth will not work anymore.

In order to delete the iOS project, go to:

Project Overview -> iOS app that you want to delete -> Configuration (Where it has some dots in the corner)

[image]
(Sorry my panel is in spanish, but you can see where the app config panel is)

You will find a `Delete application` button right in the bottom of the page.

Comment: sorry, but after checking this answer i found that it is NOT working :( 

the app is deleted but users are still getting the information from the database

Firebase say to delete the API keys and credentials but i did that and it is still getting information :(

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the iOS app from Firebase console itself.

Project settings (near project overview) -> Delete iOS APP.

[image]